# Assembly - compiler will not see my inline changes?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, att

#### Context :

Linux 64.

GCC 4.8.2 (with -O3 -march=native)

The x86_64 abi under my left hand, opened at page 21.

#### The C code :

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

    int16_t h = atoi(argv[1]) ;
    int16_t p;

  __asm__ ("mov %2, %0\n\t"
    "rol $8,%1\n\t"          
     : "=r" (p)    /* output operands */
     : "0"(p),"g"(h)/* input operands */
     :"cc");        /* clobbered operands */

  printf("%d %d\n", h, p);
  return 0;

}
```

#### The assembly code (lines underlying the problem):

```
    ...
    movl    $10, %edx
    movq    8(%rsi), %rdi
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    call    strtol
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
#APP
# 1627 "test2ptr.c" 1
    movl %ax, %dx          <- set in %dx
    rol $8,%dx

# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    movswl  %ax, %esi
    movswl  %dx, %edx <- Then this line should not appear
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ...
```

If I comment it, the result is fine.

But I cannot rely on modifying the source (unmaintainable : every time one change something in the source, one would have to come back in that spot to be sure it is still working.. no go).

#### The question :

Why is the line `movswl %dx, %edx` kept ?

It should move a long in a word. But it is already done by me and cost me one superfluous clock.

Is there any workaround ?

Is it just an option I didn't set ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified a 16 bit type, but `printf` expects 32 bit integers, your result needs to be sign extended which is what that code does. Nevertheless, if you used the proper format for `printf` both versions should produce identical output.

As usual, you don't need inline asm for a rotate, and also if you ever use a `mov` in inline asm chances are you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks (again :-) ) Jester. I corrected the mov with a movl. Actually I save 1 cpu cycle by doing so ! Nothing but it is a start. But my problem remains. What can i do to solve it ?

Comment: I changed from int16_t to int32_t and problem gone. Now my inline asm is 2 cpu cycles faster :) waw.. champagne..

Comment: But I would like to +1 you Jester : because you are like a guardian on SO for me in the assembly field and always point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So the workaround is to set int32_t and not int16_t.

Now the code is... 2 cpu cycles faster.

That is ridiculous.

But I like assembly so much now :)